# Doctrine 2.1 - native query

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have this data in database:

table: games_related

```
game_id1  |  game_id2
   3      |      2
   4      |      2
```

And I'm using this code to takie this data:

```
$rsm = new Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Game', 'g1');
$rsm->addEntityResult('Game', 'g2');
$rsm->addFieldResult('g1', 'id', 'game_id1');
$rsm->addFieldResult('g2', 'id', 'game_id2');
$result = $this->db->createNativeQuery("SELECT game_id1, game_id2 FROM games_related WHERE :game IN (game_id1, game_id2)", $rsm)->setParameter('game', $game->getId())->getResult();
```

Why `var_dump($result);` is returning `array(0) { }` when `$game->getId()` = 2  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Game` entity has a field `$id`, this would be:
the `ResultSetMapping#addFieldResult()` method expects you to call

```
$rsm->addFieldResult('g1', 'game_id1', 'id');
```

[addFieldResult()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html#field-results)